# Image not rendering .bmp SDL/C++

Tags: c++, sdl, bmp

I have recently asked a question similar to this, and have gotten great feedback. Here is the link: [Image not rendering .bmp image C++ SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75819434/image-not-rendering-bmp-image-c-sdl). I am trying to render a .bmp image using SDL on windows 11 / visual studio, but I cannot get it to render.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include "engine.cpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //Init image's pointers
    bool quit = false;
    //Render a window
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Surface *imageSurface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* windowSurface = NULL;

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Displaying Image", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);

    windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    imageSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("hello.bmp");

    SDL_BlitSurface(imageSurface, NULL, windowSurface, NULL);

    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    SDL_Delay(2000);
    while (!quit) {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Considering OP's self-answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75824735/21105992 flagging this one as typo/already fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image not rendering .bmp image C++ SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75819434/image-not-rendering-bmp-image-c-sdl)